# I'm planning to create 3 aws_vpc and peering using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I'm planning to create 3 aws_vpc and peering using terraform. My problems is all 3 config files are on a different folder. WHenn I Run terraform apply I get this error 
Error: resource 'aws_vpc_peering_connection.transit2pco' config: unknown resource 'aws_vpc.Transit-VPC' referenced in variable aws_vpc.Transit-VPC.id

```
#create a vpc in aws named PCO-VPC-Prod
resource "aws_vpc" "PCO-VPC-Prod" {
  cidr_block = "${var.pco_cidr_block}"
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name = "PCO-VPC-Prod"
  }
}

# Create a subnet to launch our instances into
resource "aws_subnet" "PCO-pub-sub-a" {
  availability_zone       = "us-west-1a"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.pco-pub-sub-a}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags {
   Name = "PCO-pub-sub-a"
    Created = "terraform"
  }
}

# Create a subnet to launch our instances into
resource "aws_subnet" "PCO-pub-sub-b" {
  availability_zone       = "us-west-1b"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.pco-pub-sub-b}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags {
    Name = "PCO-pub-sub-a"
    Created = "terraform"
  }
}

# Create a subnet to launch our instances into
resource "aws_subnet" "PCO-priv-sub-a" {
  availability_zone       = "us-west-1a"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.pco-priv-sub-a}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags {
    Name = "PCO-priv-sub-a"
    Created = "terraform"
  }
}

# Create a subnet to launch our instances into
resource "aws_subnet" "PCO-priv-sub-b" {
  availability_zone       = "us-west-1b"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.pco-priv-sub-b}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags {
   Name = "PCO-priv-sub-a"
    Created = "terraform"
  }
}

#create the public route table
resource "aws_route_table" "PCO-rt-pub" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"

    tags {
        Name = "Pco Public route table"
    }
}

#create the private route table
resource "aws_route_table" "PCO-rt-priv" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"

    tags {
        Name = "Pco Private route table"
    }
}


# Associate subnet PCO-pub-sub-a to public route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PCO-pub-sub-a-association" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.PCO-pub-sub-a.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.main_route_table_id}"
}

# Associate subnet PCO-pub-sub-b to public route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PCO-pub-sub-b-association" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.PCO-pub-sub-b.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.PCO-rt-pub.id}"
}

# Associate subnet PCO-priv-sub-a to private route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PCO-priv-sub-a-association" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.PCO-priv-sub-a.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.PCO-rt-priv.id}"
}

# Associate subnet PCO-priv-sub-b to private route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PCO-priv-sub-b-association" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.PCO-priv-sub-b.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.PCO-rt-priv.id}"
}


resource "aws_security_group" "PCO_public_subnet_security_group" {
 name = "PCO_public_sg"
 description = "PCO_public_sg"
 vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"
 tags = { Name = "PCO_public_sg"}
 ingress {
   from_port = 22
   to_port = 22
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
   ingress {
   from_port = 0
   to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["${var.pco-priv-sub-a}"]
}
    egress {
   from_port = 0
   to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "PCO_private_subnet_security_group" {
 name = "vpc2_private_sg"
 description = "vpc2_private_sg"
 vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.PCO-VPC-Prod.id}"
 tags = { Name = "vpc2_private_sg"}
   ingress {
   from_port = 0
   to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["${var.pco-pub-sub-a}"]
  }
    ingress {
   from_port = 0
   to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["${var.transit-priv-sub-a}"]
  }
    egress {
   from_port = 0
   to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "pco_public_instance" {
    ami = "ami-b2527ad2"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.PCO_public_subnet_security_group.id}"]
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.PCO-pub-sub-a.id}"
    tags {
        Name = "pco"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "pco_private_instance" {
    ami = "ami-b2527ad2"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.PCO_private_subnet_security_group.id}"]
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.PCO-priv-sub-a.id}"
    tags {
        Name = "pco2"
    }
}


/**
 * VPC peering connection.
 *
 * Establishes a relationship resource between the transit and tx VPC.
 */
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "transit2tx" {
  peer_vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.TX-VPC-Prod.id}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.Transit-VPC.id}"
  auto_accept = true

accepter {
      allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
    }
    requester {
      allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
    }
}

/**
 * Route rule.
 *
 * Creates a new route rule on the "transit" VPC main route table. All requests
 * to the "tx" VPC's IP range will be directed to the VPC peering
 * connection.
 */
resource "aws_route" "transit2tx" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.Transit-VPC.main_route_table_id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "${aws_vpc.TX-VPC-Prod.cidr_block}"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.transit2tx.id}"
}

/**
 * Route rule.
 *
 * Creates a new route rule on the "pco" VPC main route table. All
 * requests to the "pco" VPC's IP range will be directed to the VPC
 * peering connection.
 */
resource "aws_route" "tx2transit" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.TX-VPC-Prod.main_route_table_id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "${aws_vpc.Transit-VPC.cidr_block}"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.transit2tx.id}"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? And what does your peering topology look like? Is it hub and spoke? A mesh of all VPCs peering? Something else?

Comment: its a hub and spoke peering.

Comment: I guess that's your working code with a single file? What does the code roughly look like when it's split up?

Comment: all codes are on a separate .tf file and separate folders

Comment: Yes but can you post it? Because I'm guessing it looks different to the one you have posted?

Comment: edited. all codes are just identical with just the names changing

Comment: Ah, you've changed the original code. It would be best if you posted the code that was working with a single file (as you originally had) and also an example of a single spoke VPC configuration alongside (like your current question has). That allows people who are trying to answer your question to see exactly what you were trying to do when it worked and now when it's failing. If you also get an error when doing something it's a good idea to post the exact error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to use a Data Source to reference "Transit-VPC"

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html

Comment: This answer could be improved significantly by providing some example code that stands alone without needing to follow the link and referring to the official docs as appropriate for people to expand on.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.